# Opencv python конвертация изображения

Tags: python, изображения, opencv

После выполнения, кода я получаю черно-белое изображение, которое состоит из двух измерений (ширина высота) и само значение от `0` до `255` - от черного до белого. Для дальнейшего использования мне необходимо конвертировать его в `rgb8`. Например функция `cv2.floodFill` не принимает изображение, которое я получил. Вот сам код:

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# noise removal
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations = 2)
# sure background area
sure_bg = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel, iterations=3)
# Finding sure foreground area
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening, cv2.DIST_L2, 5)
ret, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform, 0.55 * dist_transform.max(), 255, 0)
# Finding unknown region
sure_fg = np.uint8(sure_fg)
unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg, sure_fg)
# Marker labelling
ret, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_fg)
# Add one to all labels so that sure background is not 0, but 1

markers = markers+10
# Now, mark the region of unknown with zero
markers[unknown == 255] = 0
markers = cv2.watershed(img, markers)
img[markers == -1] = [255, 0, 0]
cv2.imwrite('6.jpg', markers)
```

Есть ли возможность конвертировать `markers` в нормальное изображение?

Comment: Приведите ошибку, которую получаете при вызове `cv2.floodFill`

Comment: C cv2.floodFill вопрос решился тем, что я заливаю серым цветом. При попытке вывести изображение, получаю черную картинку. Вот ошибка при выполнении cvtColor:  markers=cv2.cvtColor(markers,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.error: /home/max/opencv3.0/opencv-3.2.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:9710: error: (-215) depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F in function cvtColor

Comment: Попробуйте указывать полные пути для файлов. Вероятнее всего, у вас в `img` `NoneType`.

Comment: Вот изображение которое я подаю dtype: int32
shape: (240, 480)
[[ 0  0  0 ...,  0  0  0]
 [ 0 11 11 ..., 11 11  0]
 [ 0 11 11 ..., 11 11  0]
 ..., 
 [ 0 11 11 ..., 11 11  0]
 [ 0 11 11 ..., 11 11  0]
 [ 0  0  0 ...,  0  0  0]]

Comment: Функция ждет `uint8 or uint16 or float32`, а вы ей даете `int32`. Используйте `np.ndarray.astype(np.uint8)` для вашего массива.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Команда

```
np.ndarray.astype(np.uint8)
```

помогла

Comment: @AivanF., он скопировал ответ из комментария в ответ. Всё нормально.

Comment: @Darth, он скопировал ответ из комментария в ответ. Всё нормально.